# How to kill all programs running in folders and subfolders using PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell

I searched and found an icon, but it does not close programs that are running in `subfolders`.

I want to close programs running in `subfolders`

**Note:** You have to run the code in the folder you want, if anyone knows a way to add the file path instead of adding `cd folder` before the code, that would be fine.

This is the code

```
Get-Process | ?{$_.path -and (test-path (split-path $_.path -leaf ))} | Stop-Process -Force
```

Comment: What do you really want? Delete a file, but can't as some application is holding a lock on it? Update software, but can't as it is being run? Something else?

Comment: Are you talking about child processes? What *icon* did you find?

Comment: It's not entirely clear, but it sounds like your question is in essence the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70054573/45375).