# how to do taskkill for all programs in the folder using cmd / powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

I want to do `Taskkill` for all programs ending with `exe` in a folder with `cmd` / `powershell`

Example

```
taskkill /f /im C:\folder\*.exe
```

Comment: You cannot use `taskkill.exe` like that because the `/IM` \ `IMAGENAME`, is exactly that; the basename with extension of the file. You could parse the 'folder' for the basenames of all `.exe` files files in your 'folder' first, then iterate each through the `taskkill` command utility, but you'd have to be certain that there were no other tasks with the same named files in other locations already running, _(as you would be 'kill'ing those too)_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PowerShell, something like this:

```
$files = gci "C:\Path\To\Files" -Filter "*.exe"

foreach($file in $files){
    Get-Process | 
    Where-Object {$_.Path -eq $file.FullName} | 
    Stop-Process -WhatIf
}
```

Remove the -WhatIf when you're confident that the correct processes would be stopped.

Comment: Good catch, the line continuation backticks were superfluous, I've removed them.  I included the filter for executable files as this was a requirement of the questioner; although my implementation could certainly be simplified, I felt this format provided some clarity. It should be noted that not all processes have a filepath ending in exe.

Comment: Thanks for updating. Yes, limiting the process to executables _from a given directory_ is a requirement, but my point was that you an achieve that directly by filtering `Get-Process` output by those objects whose `.Path` property's _directory_ path is the directory path of interest. This also obviates the need to worry about which filename extensions are executable. (As far as I know, only `.com` and `.exe` are _directly_ executable, resulting in processes named for the file's base name; files with other extensions listed in `$env:PATH_EXT` are executed _indirectly_.)

Comment: I agree that in almost all cases filtering Get-Process output as you suggest would be fine, but not all.  For example, executing the code in my answer to kill Docker Desktop.exe, without a filter for exe files, would attempt to kill Docker Desktop.exe and the com.docker.service process.

Comment: Interesting. What executable underlies the `com.docker.service`, and why would it be located in `C:\folder`? Conversely, if it _is_ located there, by the premise of the question it _should_ be killed (though that may fail, unless elevated).

Comment: I believe that the `com.docker.service` process is, or can be started by net.exe; essentially, it's the Docker service that runs as a Windows process. I don't think it's reasonable to attempt to kill the service if the intention is to kill the Docker desktop client.  Of course, Docker probably wouldn't be installed to `C:\folder` but I took that directory to be a placeholder.

Comment: Yes, `C:\folder` was just meant to be a placeholder for a given directory of interest, whatever its specific path may be. If `com.docker.service` is launched _via another executable_ (often: `svchost.exe`) it is _that_ executable's path that matters (for `svchost.exe`, it is the SYSTEM32 dir, so it wouldn't be included if you target any folder other than that - and targeting SYSTEM32 is definitely ill-advised). By contrast, a service that is implemented _in its own executable_ will equally be included by your approach if that executable is located in the target directory.

Comment: I agree that the usual behaviour is as per your comment, however, when the docker service is started with `net.exe` a process is spawned called `com.docker.service` and `net.exe` exits; the `com.docker.service` process shares a file path with `Docker Desktop.exe`.  Yes, this is perhaps unusual, but I gave this example to prove there are edge cases to account for when blindly stopping processes based on the `.Path` property.

Comment: The use of `net.exe start` is incidental to what executable will end up hosting the service, which is solely determined by the service's definition in the registry. The point of my previous comment was: you are _not_ avoiding any edge cases with your approach: if the service executable's directory happens to differ from the targeted directory, your approach will ignore it; if not, your approach _will_ include it.

Answer (score 2):

I would advise that you try a different built-in command utility, `WMIC.exe`:

```sh
%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe Process Where "ExecutablePath Like 'P:\\athTo\\Folder\\%'" Call Terminate 2>NUL
```

Just change `P:\\athTo\\Folder` as needed, remembering that each backward slash requires doubling. *You may have difficulties with other characters in your 'folder' name, but those are outside of the scope of my answer. To learn more about those please read, [LIKE Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/like-operator)*

Note: If you are running the command from a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file), as opposed to directly within [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd), then change the `%` character to `%%`

Comment: Certainly not an issue for the foreseeable future, but worth noting that the WMIC tool has been [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/planning/windows-10-deprecated-features).

Comment: Exactly @nimizen! not an issue for the forseeable future... We could make your statement for `taskkill.exe`, and many other built-in command line utilities, _(which whilst not showing a message saying that they're deprecated)_, many of them are essentially performing tasks which can now be performed via `powershell.exe`. Although we could say that the built-in PowerShell, `powershell.exe`, is technically deprecated in favor of PowerShell Core, i.e. `pwsh.exe`.

Comment: (To be clear: you had my +1 for a concise solution. `wmic.exe` reveals that it is deprecated if you run `wmic /?`(first nonempty line)). Thinking the deprecation logic  through to its local conclusion: In PowerShell (both editions), use [`Get-CimInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/get-ciminstance), which will continue to work in PowerShell (Core) 7+: `Get-CimInstance win32_Process -Filter "ExecutablePath Like 'P:\\athTo\\Folder\\%'" | Invoke-CimMethod -MethodName Terminate -WhatIf`

Comment: From `cmd.exe`, using `wmic.exe` is the only reasonable solution. However, from PowerShell, a solution that doesn't require delving into the query language and method invocation of CIM/WMI is available, using just the `Get-Process` and `Stop-Process` cmdlets, which, as an aside, also makes the solution work on Unix-like platforms (not requested by the OP).

Comment: * I meant _logical_ conclusion, not _local_. It's also important to note that not _all_ command-line utilities are deprecated, just because PowerShell _also_ offers cmdlets with the same functionality. Most are _not_ deprecated, including `taskkill.exe`. `wmic.exe` clearly was _selectively, explicitly_ deprecated, though I am unclear on the reasoning behind that.

Comment: This is starting, to look like a 'lets gang up on the non PowerShell guy' even though you both appear to agree that my answer is the best way to do it from [[tag:cmd]]. Incidentally I can and do use PowerShell, so your comments aren't useful to me. Please discontinue adding unnecessary noise to this post, it will irritate the OP. Incidentally as the OP mentioned both [[tag:cmd]] and [[tag:powershell]], it's worth noting that `WMIC.exe Process Where "ExecutablePath Like 'P:\\athTo\\Folder\\%'" Call Terminate` will work equally without modification in `cmd.exe`, `powershell.exe`, and `pwsh.exe`.

Comment: You both misunderstood and mischaracterized my comments, and I ask you to refrain from such testy responses in the future. No one is ganging up on you, and no one is disputing the value of your solution (hence my +1). My comments were meant to provide - hopefully helpful - additional context _for all future readers_, whether or not that group includes you personally. To put it differently: whether you _personally_ find these comments useful is not what matters, and if you don't, there's no reason to tell anyone.

Comment: @mklement0, the issue is not with both yours and nimizen's comments regarding deprecation of WMIC, those are relevant to my answer, and should therefore be underneath it. The issue is that there should not be all of the pro PowerShell stuff, under what was a cmd answer, relevant to the [[tag:cmd]] tag used. `Get`/`Invoke-CimInstance`, `Get`/`Stop-Process` comments have no place under a cmd.exe answer, and seem designed by the two commentors, who are also the competing answerers, to pitch and oversell powershell.exe against cmd.exe. That isn't what this site is for; why not just remain in lane?

Comment: This isn't about competition, and, at least metaphorically, I don't travel in lanes. The question has _both_ tags. It was you who brought up the PowerShell angle in your first response to nimizen, and I expanded on that. Only your answer has the potential to work in _both_ shells - which is great. On the flip side, an official deprecation _is_ worth mentioning - even if in practice it may not matter for years. _Users of PowerShell may want to understand how your solution fits into the PowerShell world and what the tradeoffs are_, and that is the information the comments provide.

Answer (score 1):

[nimizen's helpful PowerShell answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70056637/45375) is effective, but can be simplified:

```
Get-Process | 
  Where-Object { (Split-Path -Parent $_.Path) -eq 'C:\folder' } |
    Stop-Process -WhatIf
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf`  once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>

Note:

- The above only targets processes whose executables are located *directly* in `C:\folder`, by checking whether the (immediate) parent  path (enclosing directory) is the one of interest, using [`Split-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/split-path) `-Parent`.
- If you wanted to target executables located in `C:\Folder` *and any of its subfolders, recursively*, use the following (inside [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object)'s script block (`{ ... }`):

  ```
  $_.Path -like 'C:\folder\*'
  ```
- Unlike [Compo's helpful `wmic.exe`-based answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70054788/45375)<sup>[1]</sup>, this answer's solution also works on *Unix*-like platforms (using [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)).

---

<sup>[1] Technically, `wmic.exe` is *deprecated*, as evidenced by `wmic /?` printing `WMIC is deprecated` in red, as the first (nonempty) line. Consider using PowerShell's CIM cmdlets, such as [`Get-CimInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/get-ciminstance), instead, which has the added advantage of returning *objects* rather than text, for robust subsequent processing.</sup>